# Launching Ubuntu 17.04 colored screen freeze

Tags: usb-installation

I'm trying to install the new Ubuntu 17.04 on my Windows computer. I try to launch the test-version of the OS from the USB I'm going to install it from. But when I do, all that shows up is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjROH.jpg)

Please help, all I want to do is leave Windows behind, and embrace some Linux love...

System:
Custom homemade PC - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit|
MSI-7751 BIOS date: 10/09/13 ver: 04.06.05|
i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz|
16GB RAM|
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970|

If you need more information, just tell me what to provide and I'll do my best.

Comment: Just to be certain: Is that the first and only thing that you see? Didn't get a menu first? Have you tried booting from that same removable media (I presume a thumb drive, but there are other things that can be usb) on other machines to see if it works? How did you create it - with what software? Did you verify a hash for the iso? Have you booted the same machine from some other bootable media plugged into the SAME physical usb spot?

Comment: When you reach to "Try Ubuntu" page, press F6 and select **nomodeset** option and then select Try Ubuntu and hit enter... Ubuntu will run the setup with basic Graphics. Then you'll be able to try/install Ubuntu...

Comment: The above is correct for legacy only. For UEFI you need to edit the entry and add `nomodeset`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . You want to boot as and install in UEFI mode, necessarily if you want to dual boot and optional but highly recommended otherwise.